# Edit all iframes that start with a specific url

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is there a way to edit all iframes that start with a specific url? For example, is it possibile to add a *margin:0 auto* to the css of all iframes on a page that have a url that starts with

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player
```

??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you have mentioned jQuery in your tags you can do that using [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this:

```
$( 'iframe[src^="https://w.soundcloud.com/player"]' ).css( 'margin', '0 auto' );
```

Answer (score 0):

And with pure css would be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/obsffsfa/

```
iframe[src^="https://w.soundcloud.com/player"]{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```